# ReactJS Update or Remove item in arrayList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arraylist

This question might fall. I have a `map()` function, the data comes from the API. When something changes, I need to change the item in map without refresh page. I'm using findIndex. But some reason is wrong.
Now i have like this code:

```
const handleSubmit = values => {
    api.putItem(`users/${data.id}`, params)
    .then(res => {
        modelClose();
        console.log(res);
        let response = res.data;
        let index = userForeignInfo.findIndex(response.id);
        userForeignInfo.splice(index, 1, response);
        setLoadingBtn(false);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e.toString());
        setLoadingBtn(false);
    })
};
```

The `userForeignInfo` function in me is as follows:

```
const [userForeignInfo, setuserForeignInfo] = useState([]);
{userForeignInfo.map((item, index) =>
    (
       <li key={item.id} onClick={() => handlePassInfoShow(item)}>
            {index + 1} {item.first_name} {item.last_name}
       </li>
     )
   )}
```

there returned wrong as follows.

```
TypeError: 7 is not a function
```

Now data saved via `api.put()` method. However, the status of the array is updated after the page is reloaded. I need to change the item in the array without reloading the page. 
Where am I wrong?

Comment: do you know which line is throwing the TypeError? It should be in the console output

Answer (score 0):

You modified the variable `userForeignInfo` without using `setuserForeignInfo`. So your component will not be updated.

Try something like this:

```js
const handleSubmit = data => {  // rename "values" by "data" here
    api.putItem(`users/${data.id}`, params)  // params is not defined in your code.
    .then(res => {
        modelClose();
        console.log(res);
        let response = res.data;
        const newUserForeignInfo = [...userForeignInfo]; // Copy your array here before using splice
        let index = newUserForeignInfo.findIndex(response.id);
        newUserForeignInfo.splice(index, 1, response);
        setuserForeignInfo(newUserForeignInfo); // Update the state here
        setLoadingBtn(false);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e.toString());
        setLoadingBtn(false);
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks bor but nothing changed.

Comment: The option you advise doesn't work, and it's the same error.

Comment: Well, i just copy/paste your code but there are a some mistakes. Check your `handleSubmit` params. `values` is not used. Maybe you should rename this by `data`. `params` is not defined too.